# How come some selected popular apps in playstore have additional tags but not mine?

Tags: android, tags, google-play, google-play-console

[image]

As you can see in below image attached there are special tags like "***offline***", "***search***" and even more in some other games like "***single player***".

In my case its only single tag namely "***word***" which I set in Play store console's category section. But my app can be played offline and I want to get it notified by the user when they view my app listing while searching.

I tried finding and adding those tags in play console but its only having limited pre-defined tags. Is there a way to add these tags while building apk in some xml or it is only available to populat apps on installation/download counts?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Is anyone able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Those extra tags are added automatically by Google